# What does "Confirmed Exchanged" and "Estimated Exchanged" mean?

Tags: mining-pools

I am a newbie here, I wanted to know what does "Confirmed Exchanged" and "Estimated Exchanged" mean while fetching a user's Transaction history?

example return that I got from an API as user stats:

```
{
    "confirmed_exchanged": "0.01432604",
    "estimated_unexchanged": "0.01875723",
    "transaction_history": [
        {
            "amount": "0.04475755",
            "date": "2014-01-17 18:15:01+00:00",
            "donation": 0.0,
            "fee": 0.0
        },
        {
            "amount": "0.00326109",
            "date": "2014-01-18 16:50:02+00:00",
            "donation": 0.0,
            "fee": 0.0
        },
    ],
    "user": xx12,
    "username": "tester"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fetching a user's transaction history from what? Using what?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the question, the sample json is the response for user stats from an API.

Comment: That's not helpful. API of what? We have no idea what you're talking about unless you tell us. (A Google search for "estimated_exchanged" returns nothing. So I'm not sure how we're supposed to know what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the output of a mining pool that permits people to mine one currency and get paid in another. Most likely, "confirmed_exchanged" means the total amount the user has actually exchanged. And most likely, "estimated_unexchanged" is the amount the user has not yet exchanged, estimated because the exchange rate can change.